# Is it okay to have objects that cast themselves, even if it pollutes the API of their subclasses?

Tags: java, inheritance, type-casting

I have a base class, `Base`.  It has two subclasses, `Sub1` and `Sub2`.  Each subclass has some additional methods.  For example, `Sub1` has `Sandwich makeASandwich(Ingredients... ingredients)`, and `Sub2` has `boolean contactAliens(Frequency onFrequency)`.

Since these methods take different parameters and do entirely different things, they're completely incompatible, and I can't just use polymorphism to solve this problem.

`Base` provides most of the functionality, and I have a large collection of `Base` objects.  However, all `Base` objects are either a `Sub1` or a `Sub2`, and sometimes I need to know which they are.

It seems like a bad idea to do the following:

```
for (Base base : bases) {
    if (base instanceof Sub1) {
        ((Sub1) base).makeASandwich(getRandomIngredients());
        // ... etc.
    } else { // must be Sub2
        ((Sub2) base).contactAliens(getFrequency());
        // ... etc.
    }
}
```

So I came up with a strategy to avoid this without casting.  `Base` now has these methods:

```
boolean isSub1();
Sub1 asSub1();
Sub2 asSub2();
```

And of course, `Sub1` implements these methods as

```
boolean isSub1() { return true; }
Sub1 asSub1();   { return this; }
Sub2 asSub2();   { throw new IllegalStateException(); }
```

And `Sub2` implements them in the opposite way.

Unfortunately, now `Sub1` and `Sub2` have these methods in their own API.  So I can do this, for example, on `Sub1`.

```
/** no need to use this if object is known to be Sub1 */
@Deprecated
boolean isSub1() { return true; }

/** no need to use this if object is known to be Sub1 */
@Deprecated
Sub1 asSub1();   { return this; }

/** no need to use this if object is known to be Sub1 */
@Deprecated
Sub2 asSub2();   { throw new IllegalStateException(); }
```

This way, if the object is known to be only a `Base`, these methods are un-deprecated, and can be used to "cast" itself to a different type so I can invoke the subclass's methods on it.  This seems elegant to me in a way, but on the other hand, I'm kind of abusing Deprecated annotations as a way to "remove" methods from a class.

Since a `Sub1` instance really *is a* Base, it does make sense to use inheritance rather than encapsulation.  Is what I'm doing good?  Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean to have the `@Deprecated` and same comment on all bits in the last code example?

Comment: Yes.  They would all be deprecated for the same reason.

Comment: All 3 classes now have to know about each other.  Adding Sub3 would involve a lot of code changes, and adding Sub10 would be downright painful

Comment: This is true, but in my case I can be all but certain I'll only need two subclasses.

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave us real code. There's situations where it's appropriate to take decisions based on the particular class of something, but it's impossible to tell if you're justified in what you're doing with such contrived examples. For whatever it's worth, what you want is a [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or [tagged union](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/278856/one-of-some-type/279307#279307).

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would make things easier to give simplified examples.  Maybe I'll post new question with a broader scope of what I want to do.

Comment: @codebreaker No need to apologize, usually a minimal working example is a good thing. But when you ask "is it ok..." the answer is always "it depends".

Comment: You're just *reimplementing* casting and `instanceof`, in a way that requires lots of typing, is error-prone, and makes it hard to add more subclasses.

Comment: If `Sub1` and `Sub2` cannot be used interchangeably, then why do you treat them as such? Why not keep track of your 'sandwich-makers' and 'alien-contacters' separately?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Because they actually have a lot in common, and, actually, *most of the time*, it's useful to view them as the base class.

Comment: Then what about keeping two lists and building an iteration mechanism that can iterate both of them? For common operations, you use that mechanism - as if you had a single list of `Base` objects - and for type-specific operations you pick the list that holds the type you need.

Comment: I have met very similar problem recently. And i try to solve the problem using different approach, including `Visitor Pattern`. However, most of people under my question are oppose to using it. You may end up making your visitor as a `God class`. My problem is slightly different than yours, so i would agree `Visitor Pattern` is good for your simplified question. However, I think your real problem may be more complicated than this simplified one, you can refer this [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/284585/is-visitor-pattern-valid-in-this-scenario) to see more discussion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It doesn't always make sense to add functions to the base class, as suggested in some of the other answers. Adding too many special case functions can result in binding otherwise unrelated components together.

For example I might have an `Animal` class, with `Cat` and `Dog` components. If I want to be able to print them, or show them in the GUI it might be overkill for me to add `renderToGUI(...)` and `sendToPrinter(...)` to the base class.

The approach you are using, using type-checks and casts, is fragile - but at least does keep the concerns separated.

However if you find yourself doing these types of checks/casts often then one option is to implement the visitor / double-dispatch pattern for it. It looks kind of like this:

```
public abstract class Base {
  ...
  abstract void visit( BaseVisitor visitor );
}

public class Sub1 extends Base {
  ...
  void visit(BaseVisitor visitor) { visitor.onSub1(this); }
}

public class Sub2 extends Base {
  ...
  void visit(BaseVisitor visitor) { visitor.onSub2(this); }
}

public interface BaseVisitor {
   void onSub1(Sub1 that);
   void onSub2(Sub2 that);
}
```

Now your code becomes

```
public class ActOnBase implements BaseVisitor {
    void onSub1(Sub1 that) {
       that.makeASandwich(getRandomIngredients())
    }

    void onSub2(Sub2 that) {
       that.contactAliens(getFrequency());
    }
}

BaseVisitor visitor = new ActOnBase();
for (Base base : bases) {
    base.visit(visitor);
}
```

The main benefit is that if you add a subclass, you'll get compile errors rather than silently missing cases. The new visitor class also becomes a nice target for pulling functions into. For example it might make sense to move `getRandomIngredients()` into `ActOnBase`.

You can also extract the looping logic: For example the above fragment might become

```
BaseVisitor.applyToArray(bases, new ActOnBase() );
```

A little further massaging and using Java 8's lambdas and streaming would let you get to

```
bases.stream()
     .forEach( BaseVisitor.forEach(
       Sub1 that -> that.makeASandwich(getRandomIngredients()),
       Sub2 that -> that.contactAliens(getFrequency())
     ));
```

Which IMO is pretty much as neat looking and succinct as you can get.

Here is a more complete Java 8 example:

```
public static abstract class Base {
    abstract void visit( BaseVisitor visitor );
}

public static class Sub1 extends Base {
    void visit(BaseVisitor visitor) { visitor.onSub1(this); }

    void makeASandwich() {
        System.out.println("making a sandwich");
    }
}

public static class Sub2 extends Base {
    void visit(BaseVisitor visitor) { visitor.onSub2(this); }

    void contactAliens() {
        System.out.println("contacting aliens");
    }
}

public interface BaseVisitor {
    void onSub1(Sub1 that);
    void onSub2(Sub2 that);

    static Consumer<Base> forEach(Consumer<Sub1> sub1, Consumer<Sub2> sub2) {

        return base -> {
            BaseVisitor baseVisitor = new BaseVisitor() {

                @Override
                public void onSub1(Sub1 that) {
                    sub1.accept(that);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSub2(Sub2 that) {
                    sub2.accept(that);
                }
            };
            base.visit(baseVisitor);
        };
    }
}

Collection<Base> bases = Arrays.asList(new Sub1(), new Sub2());

bases.stream()
     .forEach(BaseVisitor.forEach(
             Sub1::makeASandwich,
             Sub2::contactAliens));
```

Comment: +1: This kind of thing is commonly used in languages that have first-class support for sum-types and pattern matching, and it is a valid design in Java, even though it is syntactically very ugly.

Comment: @Mankarse A little syntactic sugar can make it very far from ugly - I've updated it with an example.

Comment: Let's say hypothetically the OP changes their mind and decides to add a `Sub3`. Doesn't visitor have the exact same problem as `instanceof`? Now you need to add `onSub3` to the visitor and it breaks if you forget.

Comment: +1 for providing a good solution and demonstrating the Visitor pattern that's been mentioned.  This is my preferred answer.  I'm still not sure this will work for what I'm doing, but I think it's a good solution to the example I provided.

Comment: @Radiodef An advantage of using the visitor pattern over switching on type directly is that once you've added `onSub3` to the visitor interface, you get a compile error in every location you create a new Visitor that hasn't yet been updated. In contrast switching on type will at best generate a run-time error - which can be trickier to trigger.

Comment: Visitor to the rescue ;)

Comment: Can you explain what's happening in your Java 8 example?  It's not valid java, and I can't figure out what it would do if it was.

Comment: @FiveNine - `stream()` is part of the new java 8 streaming protocol. The `forEach(...)` takes a java 8 lambda and applies it to each of the elements of the stream. `BaseVisitor.forEach(...)` is a function you'd need to create that takes two java 8 lambdas of different types (one taking `Sub1`, the other taking `Sub2`) and returning a single lambda that takes a `Base` and applies the correct lambda using the visitor patter.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now after implementing it myself. Is this about right? http://git.io/vJ958  FWIW, your example should use `->` instead of `=>`

Comment: @FiveNine that looks good, but since your functions dont take arguments, instead of `sub1 -> sub1.makeASandwich()` you can just use `Sub1::makeASandwich` - which is even neater. (Thats not the case in the original example, so I had to stick with the long form lambda, rather than the method reference)

Comment: @FiveNine, if you're happy to add that complete example into the end of the answer that might help others.

Comment: I would argue your `ActOnBase` would be a `God Class` if more sub classes are created. Now it only has `getRandomIngredients` and `getFrequency`, but tomorrow, it may include much more methods as user introduce more sub classes. I have met same problem and people suggest me avoid using `Visitor Pattern`, please see the [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/284585/is-visitor-pattern-valid-in-this-scenario/284675?noredirect=1#comment586124_284675)

Comment: @Sher10ck I'd not call it a _God Class_, it still has a well defined role, and adheres to the single responsibility principle. Having said that, the aim here was to keep the structure similar to the original code, while avoiding some of the problems of direct casting etc. Once the visitor starts to become unwieldy you need to switch to another pattern. In this case I'd likely convert the visitor to a Factory for Adaptor style objects - with each Adaptor implementing  only one public function.

Answer (score 82):

From my perspective: *your design is wrong*.

Translated to natural language, you are saying the following:

Given we have `animals`, there are `cats` and `fish`. 
`animals` have properties, which are common to `cats` and `fish`. But that's not enough: there are some properties, which differentiate `cat` from `fish`, therefore you need to subclass.

Now you have the problem, that you forgot to model *movement*.
Okay. That's relatively easy:

```
for(Animal a : animals){
   if (a instanceof Fish) swim();
   if (a instanceof Cat) walk();
}
```

But that is a wrong design. The correct way would be:

```
for(Animal a : animals){
    animal.move()
}
```

Where `move` would be shared behavior implemented differently by each animal.

> Since these methods take different parameters and do entirely different things, they're completely incompatible, and I can't just use polymorphism to solve this problem.

This means: your design is broken.

My recommendation: refactor `Base`, `Sub1` and `Sub2`.

Comment: Okay, but refactor it *how*?

Comment: If you would offer actual code, I could make recommendations.

Comment: @ThomasJunk You need to find the right abstraction level for your classes, it seems like you are skipping quite a few here between the base and the sub classes

Comment: @Zavior I am sure, you meant not me ;)

Comment: @ThomasJunk Okay, if we're talking about animals, we can use `Dragon` as the example.  We have `RegularDragon`s with `Head head()` and `TwoHeadedDragon`s with `Head left()` and `Head right()`.  Since each head can do its own thing, we have to handle each one independently.  `Dragon` would then have `isTwoHeaded()`, `asTwoHeaded()`, and `asRegular()` or something.  Is there a better way to represent Dragons?

Comment: Say, you want to attack an enemy, you have the common behaviour "head-attack", which both dragons implement, but differently: one uses his head, the other dragon uses one or both heads to attack. It's up to them.

Comment: That makes sense, but I think I sort of used a bad example.  The actual code I'm working on that led to this question is kind of complicated.  I'll see if I can come up with a better way to represent it that does a better job of showing why it's more difficult than that.

Comment: This doesn't account for the return type difference from the sample.

Comment: @Sign you're right, yeah, that wasn't a great example.

Comment: I think my overall question is: I think my type hierarchy makes sense (though maybe not), so is there a problem with what I'm currently doing with the self-casting?

Comment: @codebreaker If you agree that your example wasn't good, I recommend accepting this answer and then writing a new question.  Don't revise the question to have a different example or the existing answers won't make sense.

Comment: Don't worry, I won't pull a "chameleon question."  I'm still not satisfied with this answer, though, because it doesn't really answer my initial question, and it doesn't tell me how I can resolve my concerns.

Comment: So it's clear this is the preferred answer, but there's nothing I can do with it.  I mean, what if cats could make sandwiches, and fish could talk to aliens?  Would this solution really help?  I know you said I need to provide more "real" code, and I think I'll do that, I just don't know why everyone thinks this solves the problem.  No offense.

Comment: @codebreaker I think this "solves" the problem by answering the *real* question. The real question being: How do I solve my problem? Refactor your code properly. Refactor so that you `.move()` or `.attack()` and properly abstract `that` part - instead of having `.swim()`, `.fly()`, `.slide()`, `.hop()`, `.jump()`, `.squirm()`, `.phone_home()`, etc. How do you refactor properly? Unknown without better examples... but still generally the right answer - unless example code and more details suggest otherwise.

Comment: @WernerCD You're assuming all of the methods I want to call are some kind of mutative method.  I probably should have specified: most of the methods are getter-like, and return different properties that are completely incompatible.  It in no way fits into some nice hierarchy like animal movement does.  I probably should have picked a better example.  I feel pretty confident in saying that polymorphism just *is not the answer*.  Again, I'll post another question and attempt to explain this a better way.

Comment: @codebreaker If your class hierarchy leads you to situations like this, then *by definition* it doesn't make sense

Comment: @codebreaker well hopefully a more robust example can lead to other suggestions that make more sense than "Refactor it". Maybe inheritance? Each class implements `ICopy` and `IPrint`, but since they are different enough, maybe they shouldn't come from the same base class... since one also has a scanner, the other has a coffee maker and the third is installed in a helicopter?

Comment: @Patrick-It isn't true that it doesn't make sense. This type of problem occurs when the design made sense and was possibly pretty good but then later requirements caused things to get messy. This is the same kind of problem that resulted in creating the Component-Entity-System Architecture that is widely used in game programming. e.g. The initial design with a Move method on the interface worked perfectly. A bird would fly, a person would walk. But then your game added a Dragon that could either fly or walk. Then it starts becoming messy as the original design makes sense but isn't good.

Comment: @codebreaker If you're looping over all your objects and telling them to do something then obviously those things have something in common. This answer is telling you to figure out a name for the shared things, place them on the base class as virtual or abstract methods, and then override them in the sub classes. Is that specific enough?

Comment: @codebreaker Related to Crisfole's last comment, there's another way of looking at it that might help.  For example, with the `move` vs `fly`/`run`/etc, that can be explained in one sentence as:  You should be telling the object what to do, not how to do it.  In terms of accessors, as you mention is more like the real case in a comment here, you should ask the object questions, not inspect its state.

Answer (score 9):

It's a little hard to imagine a circumstance where you have a group of things and want them to either make a sandwich or contact aliens. In most cases where you find such casting you will operate with one type - e.g. in clang you filter a set of nodes for declarations where [getAsFunction](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html) returns non-null, rather than doing something different for each node in the list.

It might be that you need a perform a sequence of action and it's not actually relevant that the objects performing the action are related.

So instead of a list of `Base`, work on the list of actions

```
for (RandomAction action : actions)
   action.act(context);
```

where

```
interface RandomAction {
    void act(Context context);
} 

interface Context {
    Ingredients getRandomIngredients();
    double getFrequency();
}
```

You can, if appropriate, have Base implement a method to return the action, or whatever other means you need to select the action from the instances in your base list (since you say you can't use polymorphism, so presumably the action to take is not a function of the class but some other property of the bases; otherwise you'd just give Base the act(Context) method )

Comment: You get that my sort of absurd methods are designed to show the differences in what the classes can do once their subclass is known (and that they have nothing to do with each other), but I think having a `Context` object just makes matters worse.  I might as well just be passing in `Object`s to the methods, casting them, and hoping they're the right type.

Comment: @codebreaker you really need to clarify your question then - in most systems there would be a valid reason for calling a bunch of functions agnostic of what they do; for example to process rules on an event or perform a step in a simulation. Usually such systems have a context in which the actions occur. If the 'getRandomIngredients' and 'getFrequency' are not related, then then shouldn't be in the same object, and you need yet a different approach, such as having the actions capture the source of ingredients or frequency.

Comment: You're right, and I don't think I can salvage this question.  I ended up picking a bad example, so I'll probably just post another one.  The getFrequency() and getIngredients() were just placeholders.  I probably should have just put "..." as the arguments to make it more apparent that I wouldn't know what they are.

Comment: This is IMO the right answer.  Understand that the `Context` doesn't need to be a new class, or even an interface.  Usually the context is just the caller, so calls are in the form `action.act(this)`.  If `getFrequency()` and `getRandomIngredients()` are static methods, you might not even need a context.

This is how I would implement say, a job queue, which your problem sounds an awful lot like.

Comment: Also this is mostly identical to the visitor pattern solution.  The difference is you're implementing the Visitor::OnSub1()/Visitor::OnSub2() methods as Sub1::act()/Sub2::act()

Comment: @QuestionC yes, I read the assertion that can't be solved polymorphically to exclude the visitor option operating on the list of Bases themselves

Answer (score 4):

How about if you have your subclasses implement one or more interfaces that define what they can do ? Something like this:

```
interface SandwichCook
{
    public void makeASandwich(String[] ingredients);
}

interface AlienRadioSignalAwarable
{
    public void contactAliens(int frequency);

}
```

Then your classes will look like this:

```
class Sub1 extends Base implements SandwichCook
{
    public void makeASandwich(String[] ingredients)
    {
        //some code here
    }
}

class Sub2 extends Base implements AlienRadioSignalAwarable
{
    public void contactAliens(int frequency)
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

And your for-loop will become:

```
for (Base base : bases) {
    if (base instanceof SandwichCook) {
        base.makeASandwich(getRandomIngredients());
    } else if (base instanceof AlienRadioSignalAwarable) {
        base.contactAliens(getFrequency());
    }
}
```

Two major advantages to this approach:

- no casting involved
- you can have each subclass implement as many interfaces as you want, which does provide some flexibility for future changes.

PS: Sorry for the names of the interfaces, I couldn't think of anything cooler at that particular moment :D .

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem.  You still need the cast in the for loop.  (If you don't then you don't need the cast in OP's example either).

Answer (score 2):

The approach can be a good one in cases where almost any type within a family will *either* be directly usable as an implementation of some interface which meets some criterion *or* can be used to create an implementation of that interface.  The built-in collection types would IMHO have benefited from this pattern, but since they don't for purposes of example I'll invent a collection interface `BunchOfThings<T>`.

Some implementations of `BunchOfThings` are mutable; some aren't.  In many cases, an object Fred might want to hold something it can use as a `BunchOfThings` and know that nothing other than Fred will be able to modify it.  This requirement may be satisfied in two ways:

1. Fred knows that it holds the only references to that `BunchOfThings`, and no outside reference to that `BunchOfThings` ir its internals exists anywhere in the universe.  If nobody else has a reference to the `BunchOfThings` or its internals, nobody else will be able to modify it, so the constraint will be satisfied.
2. Neither the `BunchOfThings`, nor any of its internals to which outside references exist, can be modified via any means whatsoever.  If absolutely nobody can modify a `BunchOfThings`, then the constraint will be satisfied.

One way of satisfying the constraint would be to unconditionally copy any object received (recursively processing any nested components).  Another would be to test whether a received object promises immutability and, if not, make a copy of it, and do likewise with any nested components.  An alternative, which is apt to be cleaner than the second and faster than the first, is to offer an `AsImmutable` method which asks an object to make an immutable copy of itself (using `AsImmutable` on any nested components that support it).

Related methods may also be provided for `asDetached` (for use when code receives an object and doesn't know if it will want to mutate it, in which case a mutable object should be replaced with a new mutable object, but an immutable object can be kept as-is), `asMutable` (in cases where an object knows that it will hold an object earlier returned from `asDetached`, i.e. either an unshared reference to a mutable object or a sharable reference to a mutable one), and `asNewMutable` (in cases where code receives an outside reference and knows it's going to want to mutate a copy of the data therein--if the incoming data is mutable there's no reason to start by making an immutable copy which is going to be immediately used to create a mutable copy and then abandoned).

Note that while the `asXX` methods may return slightly different types, their real role is to ensure that the returned objects will satisfy program needs.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the issue of whether you have a good design or not, and supposing it's good or at least acceptable, I would want to consider the capabilities of the subclasses, not the type.

Therefore, either:

---

Move some knowledge of the existence of sandwiches and aliens into the base class, even though you know some instances of the base class can't do it. Implement it in the base class to throw exceptions, and change the code to:

```
if (base.canMakeASandwich()) {
    base.makeASandwich(getRandomIngredients());
    // ... etc.
} else { // can't make sandwiches, must be able to contact aliens
    base.contactAliens(getFrequency());
    // ... etc.
}
```

Then one or both subclasses overrides `canMakeASandwich()`, and only one implements each of `makeASandwich()` and `contactAliens()`.

---

Use interfaces, not concrete subclasses, to detect what capabilities a type has. Leave the base class alone, and change the code to:

```
if (base instanceof SandwichMaker) {
    ((SandwichMaker)base).makeASandwich(getRandomIngredients());
    // ... etc.
} else { // can't make sandwiches, must be able to contact aliens
    ((AlienContacter)base).contactAliens(getFrequency());
    // ... etc.
}
```

or possibly (and feel free to ignore this option if it doesn't suit your style, or for that matter any Java style you'd consider sensible):

```
try {
    ((SandwichMaker)base).makeASandwich(getRandomIngredients());
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    ((AlienContacter)base).contactAliens(getFrequency());
}
```

Personally I don't *usually* like the latter style of catching a half-expected exception, because of the risk of inappropriately catching a `ClassCastException` coming out of `getRandomIngredients` or `makeASandwich`, but YMMV.

Comment: Catching ClassCastException is just ew. That's the entire purpose of instanceof.

Comment: @Radiodef: true, but one purpose of `<` is to avoid catching `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and some folks decide to do that too. No accounting for taste ;-) Basically my "problem" here is I work in Python, where the preferred style usually is that catching *any* exception is preferable to testing in advance whether the exception will occur, no matter how simple the advance test would be. Maybe the possibility just isn't worth mentioning in Java.

Comment: @SteveJessop »It's easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission« is the slogan ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here we have an interesting case of a base class that downcasts itself to its own derived classes. We know full well this is normally bad, but if we want to say we found a good reason, let us look and see what the constraints on this might be:

1. We can cover all the cases in the base class.
2. No foreign derived class would have to add a new case, ever.
3. We can live with the policy for which call to make being under the control of the base class.
4. But we know from our science that the policy of what to do in a derived class for a method not in the base class is that of the derived class and not the base class.

If 4 then we have:
5. The policy of the derived class is always under the same political control as the policy of the base class.

2 and 5 both directly imply that we can enumerate all derived classes, which means that there aren't supposed to be any outside derived classes.

But here's the thing. If they're all yours you can replace the if with an abstraction that is a virtual method call (even if it's a nonsense one) and get rid of the if and self-cast. Therefore, don't do it. A better design is available.

Answer (score -1):

Put an abstract method in the base class which does one thing in Sub1 and the other thing in Sub2, and call that abstract method in your mixed loops.

```
class Sub1 : Base {
    @Override void doAThing() {
        this.makeASandwich(getRandomIngredients());
    }
}

class Sub2 : Base {
    @Override void doAThing() {
        this.contactAliens(getFrequency());
    }
}

for (Base base : bases) {
    base.doAThing();
}
```

Note that this may require other changes depending on how getRandomIngredients and getFrequency are defined. But, honestly, inside the class that contacts aliens is probably a better place to define getFrequency anyway.

Incidentally, your asSub1 and asSub2 methods are *definitely* bad practice. If you're going to do this, do it by casting. There's nothing these methods give you that casting doesn't.

Comment: Your answer suggests you didn't read through the question completely: polymorphism just won't cut it here.  There are several methods on each of Sub1 and Sub2, these are just examples, and "doAThing" doesn't really mean anything.  It doesn't correspond to anything that I'd be doing. Additionally, as for your last sentence: how about guaranteed type safety?

Comment: @codebreaker - It corresponds exactly to what you're doing in the loop in the example. If that has no meaning, don't write the loop. If it doesn't make sense as a method it doesn't make sense as a loop body.

Comment: And your methods "guarantee" type safety the same way casting does: by throwing an exception if the object is the wrong type.

Comment: I realize I picked a bad example.  The problem is most of the methods in the subclasses are more like getters than mutative methods.  These classes don't do things themselves, just provide data, mostly.  Polymorphism won't help me there.  I'm dealing with producers, not consumers.  Also: throwing an exception is a runtime guarantee, which isn't as good as compile-time.

Comment: My point is _your_ code only provides a runtime guarantee as well. There's nothing stopping someone from failing to check isSub2 before calling asSub2.

Comment: Oh, I see, yes, that is true.  I just like that it stops people from casting, and gives them a better idea of what they should be doing.

Comment: @codebreaker Casting isn't bad. IMHO this is one of those cases where you really have to cast.

Comment: +1 for giving a general answer: whenever you have code in a base class that needs to know which subclass it's dealing with, you can *always* move that code into the subclasses themselves. Yes, sometimes this may be a bit awkward, leaving you with methods that may seem overly specific in their responsibilities, but it's the only solution to this vaguely described problem that *always* works (and still allows e.g. adding more subclasses without changing the base class).

Answer (score -2):

You could push both `makeASandwich` and `contactAliens` into the base class and then implement them with dummy implementations. Since the return types/arguments can't be resolved to a common base class.

```
class Sub1 extends Base{
    Sandwich makeASandwich(Ingredients i){
        //Normal implementation
    }
    boolean contactAliens(Frequency onFrequency){
        return false;
    }
 }
class Sub2 extends Base{
    Sandwich makeASandwich(Ingredients i){
        return null;
    }
    boolean contactAliens(Frequency onFrequency){
       // normal implementation
    }
 }
```

There are obvious downsides to this sort of thing, like what that means for the contract of the method and what you can and cannot infer about the context of the result. You can't think since I failed to make a sandwich the ingredients got used up in the attempt etc.

Comment: I did think about doing this, but it violates the Liskov Substitution Principle, and isn't as nice to work with, e.g., when you type "sub1." and the autocomplete comes up, you see makeASandwich but not contactAliens.

Answer (score -4):

What you are doing is perfectly legitimate.  Do not pay attention to the naysayers who merely reiterate dogma because they read it in some books.  Dogma has no place in engineering.

I have employed the same mechanism a couple of times, and I can say with confidence that the java runtime could have also done the same thing in at least one place that I can think of, thus improving performance, usability, and readability of code that uses it.

Take for example `java.lang.reflect.Member`, which is the base of `java.lang.reflect.Field` and `java.lang.reflect.Method`.  (The actual hierarchy is a bit more complicated than that, but that's irrelevant.)  Fields and methods are vastly different animals: one has a value that you can get or set, while the other has no such thing, but it can be invoked with a number of parameters and it may return a value. So, fields and methods are both members, but the things you can do with them are about as different from each other as making sandwiches vs. contacting aliens.

Now, when writing code that uses reflection we very often have a `Member` in our hands, and we know that it is either a `Method` or a `Field`, (or, rarely, something else,) and yet we have to do all the tedious `instanceof` to figure out precisely what it is and then we have to cast it to get a proper reference to it.  (And this is not only tedious, but it also does not perform very well.) The `Method` class could have very easily implemented the pattern that you are describing, thus making the life of thousands of programmers easier.

Of course, this technique is only viable in small, well-defined hierarchies of closely coupled classes that you have (and will always have) source-level control of: you don't want to be doing such a thing if your class hierarchy is liable to be extended by people who are not at liberty to refactor the base class.

Here is how what I have done differs from what you have done:

- The base class provides a default implementation for the entire `asDerivedClass()` family of methods, having each one of them return `null`.
- Each derived class only overrides one of the `asDerivedClass()` methods, returning `this` instead of `null`.  It does not override any of the rest, nor does it want to to know anything about them. So, no `IllegalStateException`s are thrown.
- The base class also provides `final` implementations for the entire `isDerivedClass()` family of methods, coded as follows: `return asDerivedClass() != null;`  This way, the number of methods that need to be overriden by derived classes is minimized.
- I have not been using `@Deprecated` in this mechanism because I did not think of it.  Now that you gave me the idea, I will put it to use, thanks!

C# has a related mechanism built-in via the use of the `as` keyword.  In C# you can say `DerivedClass derivedInstance = baseInstance as DerivedClass` and you will get a reference to a `DerivedClass` if your `baseInstance` was of that class, or `null` if it was not. This (theoretically) performs better than `is` followed by cast, (`is` is the admittedly better named C# keyword for `instanceof`,) but the custom mechanism that we have been hand-crafting performs even better: the pair of `instanceof`-and-cast operations of Java, as well as the `as` operator of C# do not perform as fast as the single virtual method call of our custom approach.

I hereby put forth the proposition that this technique should be declared to be **a pattern** and that a nice name should be found for it.

## Gee, thanks for the downvotes!

A summary of the controversy, to save you from the trouble of reading the comments:

People's objection appears to be that the original design was wrong, meaning that you should never have vastly different classes deriving from a common base class, or that even if you do, the code which uses such a hierarchy should never be in the position of having a base reference and needing to figure out the derived class. Therefore, they say, the self-casting mechanism proposed by this question and by my answer, which improves the use of the original design, should never have been necessary in the first place. (They don't really say anything about the self-casting mechanism itself, they only complain about the nature of designs that the mechanism is meant to be applied to.)

However, in the example above I have **already** shown that the creators of the java runtime did in fact choose precisely such a design for the `java.lang.reflect.Member`, `Field`, `Method` hierarchy, and in the comments below I **also** show that the creators of the C# runtime independently arrived at an **equivalent** design for the `System.Reflection.MemberInfo`, `FieldInfo`, `MethodInfo` hierarchy.  So, these are two different real world scenarios which are sitting right under everyone's nose and which have demonstrably workable solutions using precisely such designs.

That's what all the following comments boil down to.  The self-casting mechanism is hardly mentioned.

Comment: This is my preferred answer right now, and not just because it's saying I'm doing the right thing.  The circumstances you're describing (closely-coupled classes, small hierarchy) sound just like what I'm doing.  Maybe I went too far by using my silly, disparate method examples, but the point is my subclasses actually do share a good deal of functionality, but also branch significantly (somewhat like `Member`), so I think this answer works here.

Comment: It's legitimate if you designed yourself into a box, sure. That's the problem with a lot of these types of questions. People make decisions in other areas of the design which force these type of hackish solutions when the real solution is to figure out why you ended up in this situation in the first place. A decent design won't get you here. I'm currently looking at a 200K SLOC application and I'm not seeing anywhere that we needed to do this. So it isn't just something people read in a book. Not getting in these types of situations is simply the end result of following good practices.

Comment: @Dunk I just showed that the need for such a mechanism exists for example in the `java.lang.reflection.Member` hierarchy. The creators of the java runtime got in this type of situation, I don't suppose you would say they designed themselves into a box, or blame them for not following some kind of best practices?  So, the point I am making here is that once you have this type of situation this mechanism is a good way to improve things.

Comment: I'm all for avoiding this situation if I can, I just can't figure out a better way to represent a type hierarchy where two subclasses share a lot of members, but also diverge quite a bit such that they need separate handling.

Comment: @MikeNakis The creators of Java have made plenty of bad decisions, so that alone doesn't say much. At any rate, using a visitor would be better than doing an ad-hoc test-then-cast.

Comment: @codebreaker-A possible strategy to come up with a better design would be to write some Use-Cases for just your Base class. Try to do a quick design based purely on the Use-Cases. Try not to let the existing design influence your new design. I'll bet you solve your problem. I find a 4x6 whiteboard indispensable for these types of situations.

Comment: @Doval C# has an equivalent hierarchy starting with `System.Reflection.MemberInfo` which is extended by `FieldInfo`, `MethodInfo`, etc. I think it is highly unlikely that the creators of C# made the same bad decisions.

Comment: Additionally, the example is flawed. There is a `Member` interface, but it only serves to check the access qualifiers. Typically, you get a list of methods or properties and use that directly (without mixing them, so no `List<Member>` appears), so you do not need to cast. Note that `Class` does not provide a `getMembers()` method. Of course, a clueless programmer might create the `List<Member>`, but that would make as little sense as making it a `List<Object>` and adding some `Integer` or `String` to it.

Comment: @Mike-There are special case situations where these methods are useful. Particularly when serializing/deserializing objects and for being able to programmatically examine classes when building productivity tools like Intellisense. Just because something exists doesn't mean it is a good idea or was intended to be used for normal purposes.

Comment: @MikeNakis "A lot of people do it" and "Famous person does it" are not real arguments. Antipatterns are both bad ideas and widely used by definition, yet those excuses would justify their use. Give real reasons for using some design or another. My issue with ad-hoc casting is that every user of your API has to get the casting right every single time they do it. A visitor only needs to be correct once. Hiding the casting behind some methods and returning `null` instead of an exception doesn't make it much better. All else being equal, the visitor is safer while doing the same job.

Comment: @SJuan76 yes, `Member` is an interface.  The common base class is `AccessibleObject`.  Same thing.  And in C# `System.Reflection.MemberInfo` is an actual class, not an interface.

Comment: @Doval-I agree with you conceptually but Visitor does usually obfuscate things. "Easy to understand" is a very close 2nd to "It works" in my book. Like I said, I looked at my current code and about the only places where we even care about the type is when using .Net functionality (e.g. XmlSerializer, CompareTo, QueueUserWorkItem). Other than that we call GetType for some log entries to report which derived class is creating the log entry, only use typeof when converting strings to Enums, and not much more. So I'm convinced this is solvable by an easy to understand design.

Comment: @SJuan76 and yes, `java.lang.Class` does not have `getMembers()`, but we do often need to put all members in a list.  And in C# `System.Reflection.MemberInfo` has `MemberInfo[] GetMembers()`, `MemberInfo[] FindMembers()`, etc.

Comment: @Doval I did not say "A lot of people do it", nor "Famous person does it".  I said "look here, a real world scenario right under your nose that has a demonstrably workable solution using precisely such a construct". Actually, two manifestations of the same construct in two different languages.

Comment: @MikeNakis of course it is somehow legitimate - since the language allows it. Many things are legitimate, but that doesn't mean, that it makes sense do to such things. It is like putting training wheels on a car with three tires to make it drive somehow.

Comment: @ThomasJunk no, it is more like someone using a perfectly good solution to a rarely occurring but well defined problem, and everyone laughing at them because they have never seen such a thing before.

Comment: The solution may be sound in this case, but the problem is artificial, since with better design it would not occur. And no: no one is laughing.

Comment: And because it is a sound solution, I did not downvote your answer, even if it doesn't really help either.

Comment: @ThomasJunk the fact that the creators of the java runtime and the C# runtime independently arrived at the same design is a very strong indication that there is no better design, or that a design which would look better in the eyes of a few purists would in fact be worse in the eyes of the far more people who would actually have to use it.  Yeah, pragmatism is a bitch.

Comment: I'm unclear why you've rejected the visitor pattern. This is the traditional OO route to deal with precisely the scenario you're describing.

Comment: Also RE your example, I'm not sure what situation you'd say "I want to do one, field-specific thing if I'm holding a field, and another, method-specific thing, if I'm holding a method, but I don't know which I have".

Comment: @BenAaronson the visitor pattern is one way to go, but it is a hassle. I mean, by that token, instanceof-and-cast is also a way to go, and even less of a hassle than the visitor pattern.  We did not suggest that the self-casting mechanism achieves something which cannot be achieved otherwise, we are only proposing a means of reducing hassle.

Comment: @BenAaronson a trivial situation where you would want to do this: suppose you have all the members of a class in a collection, and you just want to print their definitions.

Comment: @MikeNakis Visitor pattern only needs to be a hassle if you want to be able to access or visit non-public members, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @MikeNakis: That Java and C# do it is no indication that there is no better design.  Java didn't put reflection in originally, so it would not be surprising if they needed an ugly hack to make it work when they bolted it on later.  It isn't anti-pragmatic to reject ugly hacks if you don't need them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23308/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-nakis-is-it-okay-to-have-objects-that-cast-themselv).

Comment: Ah, there really should be a badge for an answer which receives 5 or more upvotes and twice the downvotes.  [ • Controversial ] or something.